# How to use XF.Material library with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm looking for the best way to use *app-bar-customization* from [XF.Material Library](https://github.com/contrix09/XF-Material-Library) in project based on MvvmCross. 
App bar customization can be realized by:

```
<ContentPage 
     xmlns:material="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material.Forms" 
     material:MaterialNavigationPage.AppBarColor="#2c3e50"
     material:MaterialNavigationPage.AppBarTitleTextFontFamily="Roboto"
     material:MaterialNavigationPage.AppBarTitleTextFontSize="14"
     material:MaterialNavigationPage.StatusBarColor="#1B3147"
     material:MaterialNavigationPage.AppBarTitleTextAlignment="Start">
    /* Content goes here * 
</ ContentPage>
```

The main problem is that properties can be used on pages that are navigated through the **MaterialNavigationPage** control (from XF.Material). In my case navigation is based on **IMvxNavigationService** from MvvmCross.

What is the best solution which combine app bar customization with navigation service from MvvmCross?